# Como eu consigo montar um menu e submenus de acordo com perfil de usuários?

Tags: php, mysql

Eu tenho um sistema de menu e submenu que é motado atras de uma base de dados:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `app_menu_tmp` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `label` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `link` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `parent` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `sort` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_swedish_ci;

-- Copiando dados para a tabela app.app_menu_tmp: ~16 rows (aproximadamente)
INSERT INTO `app_menu_tmp` (`id`, `label`, `link`, `parent`, `sort`) VALUES
    (1, 'PHP', '#', 0, 1),
    (2, 'Tutorials', '#', 1, 2),
    (4, 'Arrays', '#', 2, NULL),
    (5, 'Operators', '#', 2, NULL),
    (6, 'Arithmetic operators', '#', 5, NULL),
    (7, 'Assignment operators', '$', 5, NULL),
    (8, 'Java', '#', 0, 3),
    (9, 'Tutorials', '', 8, NULL),
    (10, 'Programs', '', 8, NULL),
    (11, 'JavaScript', '#', 0, 4),
    (12, 'Contact', '#', 0, 10),
    (13, 'CSS', '', 0, 9),
    (14, 'Tutorials', '', 13, NULL),
    (15, 'Servlet', '', 9, NULL),
    (16, 'JSP', '', 9, NULL),
    (3, 'Scripts', '#', 1, NULL);
```

E tenho a pagina em PHP que monta esse menu:

```
<?php
include_once("connection.php");
$query = "SELECT id, label, link, parent FROM app_menu_tmp ORDER BY  sort ASC, label";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query) or die("database error:" . mysqli_error($conn));
// Create an array to conatin a list of items and parents
$menus = array(
    'items' => array(),
    'parents' => array()
);
// Builds the array lists with data from the SQL result
while ($items = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    // Create current menus item id into array
    $menus['items'][$items['id']] = $items;
    // Creates list of all items with children
    $menus['parents'][$items['parent']][] = $items['id'];
    //echo  $items;
}

// function to create dynamic treeview menus
function createMenu($parent, $menu)
{
    $html = "";
    if (isset($menu['parents'][$parent])) {
        // $html .= '<ul class="sina-menu sina-menu-right" data-in="fadeInLeft" data-out="fadeInOut">';
        foreach ($menu['parents'][$parent] as $itemId) {
            if (!isset($menu['parents'][$itemId])) {
                $html .= "<li >
                         <a  href='" . $menu['items'][$itemId]['link'] . "'>" . $menu['items'][$itemId]['label'] . "</a>
                     </li>";
            }
            if (isset($menu['parents'][$itemId])) {
                $html .= "<li class='dropdown'>
                  <a class='dropdown-toggle' data-toggle='dropdown' href='" . $menu['items'][$itemId]['link'] . "'>" . $menu['items'][$itemId]['label'] .  "</a>";
                $html .= '<ul class="dropdown-menu">';
                $html .= createMenu($itemId, $menu);
                $html .= '</ul>';
                $html .= "</li>";
            }
        }
        // $html .= "</ul>";
    }
    return $html;
}
```

Até ai tudo ok, os menus e sybmenus são tratados de forma correta e exibidos no site.

Porém, o site que estou montando eu tenho ususário e cada qual com perfil de acesso e de acordo com esse perfil eu gostaria de montar os menus e submenus, tabela basica dos ususarios:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `app_menu_user_temp` (
  `user_id` bigint(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_menu` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=100 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb3 COLLATE=utf8mb3_general_ci ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC;

-- Copiando dados para a tabela app.app_menu_user_temp: ~2 rows (aproximadamente)
INSERT INTO `app_menu_user_temp` (`user_id`, `user_menu`) VALUES
    (1, '1,2,17'),
    (2, '1,8,13');
```

Então, de acordo com o usuario com id1, seria exibido somente os menus e submenus correspondentes a tabela de menus (Menu: PHP, Submenus: Tutorials e Scripts.)

A minha dificuldade é cruzar ou trazer a lista de menus de dentro da tabela ussuarios (1,2,17) e adicionar essa informação na função que monta o menu, exibindo assim somente o que está associado ao usuario.

Agluém poderia me dar uma luz?
Obrigado.

Comment: Use  [FIND_IN_SET](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_find_in_set.asp)  com subconsulta. Ex.: SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM usuarios WHERE usuario_id="1" AND FIND_IN_SET(tabela.id, menus))